# Remove sequential number from permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm organizing some custom post types by taxonomy so that my URLs would look like

```
/small-groups/spring-2015/date-your-mate
/small-groups/fall-2015/date-your-mate
```

The `spring-2015` and `fall-2015` are the slugs of my custom taxonomy.

However, when Wordpress generates the permalinks for the 2nd  "Date Your Mate" it comes back with (notice the `-2`)

```
/small-groups/fall-2015/date-your-mate-2
```

Is there an option that I can use to turn that off so that the system queries with in the taxonomy and not need any sequential suffix (the `-2` part)?

I'm guessing that this can be changed by hooking into the `wp_unique_post_slug` filter, but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use pages for your purpose, but as in the comments in [wp-includes/post.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3701) line 3701 (in the `wp_unique_post_slug` function), you can use identical slugs for pages in different trees:

```
/*
 * Page slugs must be unique within their own trees. Pages are in a separate
 * namespace than posts so page slugs are allowed to overlap post slugs.
 */
```

There seems to have been a plugin for what you want [a few years ago](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2421), but it has disappeared since.

Right now I don't see a way to do it without getting at the core code.